# Get configuration for custom module

Tags: magento2, module, helper, system-config

I'm trying to get a configuration for my custom module

My Custom module overrides `\Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable`

With the following Code:

```
namespace Vendor\swatchExtender\Block;


use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product as CatalogProduct;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ConfigurableAttributeData;
use Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer;
use Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data as SwatchData;
use Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media;
use Magento\Swatches\Model\Swatch;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Swatches\Model\SwatchAttributesProvider;

class Configurable extends \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable
{
    protected function extractNecessarySwatchData(array $swatchDataArray)
    {
        $result['type'] = $swatchDataArray['type'];

        if ($result['type'] == Swatch::SWATCH_TYPE_VISUAL_IMAGE && !empty($swatchDataArray['value'])) {
            $result['value'] = $this->swatchMediaHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage(
                Swatch::SWATCH_IMAGE_NAME,
                $swatchDataArray['value']
            );
            $result['thumb'] = $this->swatchMediaHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage(
                Swatch::SWATCH_THUMBNAIL_NAME,
                $swatchDataArray['value']
            );
        } else {
            $result['value'] = $swatchDataArray['value'];
        }
        $result['custom_parameter'] = 'value';
    }

}
```

But now i want to read the configuation parameters from the admin-panel.

I have created a Helper data Class:

```
namespace Vendor\swatchExtender\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function getConfig($config_path)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        $config_path,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

But i have no idea how to access the Helper/data, everything i tried will brake the Configurable class, because of the parent __Construct,

How can i Access my Helper/Data class ?

Comment: you want use helper function inside block file?

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal I have extend / replaced the original function, to add some extra output, but now i want to get some parameters from the configuration in the admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your constructor should like this:**

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    ArrayUtils $arrayUtils,
    EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
    Data $helper,
    CatalogProduct $catalogProduct,
    CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
    PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
    ConfigurableAttributeData $configurableAttributeData,
    SwatchData $swatchHelper,
    Media $swatchMediaHelper,
    array $data = [],
    SwatchAttributesProvider $swatchAttributesProvider = null,
    \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $helper
) {
    $this->helper = $helper;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $arrayUtils,
        $jsonEncoder,
        $helper,
        $catalogProduct,
        $currentCustomer,
        $priceCurrency,
        $configurableAttributeData,
        $swatchHelper,
        $swatchMediaHelper
        $data
        $swatchAttributesProvider
    );
}
```

Now you can use `$this->helper` to call helper function

```
class Configurable extends \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable
{
    protected function extractNecessarySwatchData(array $swatchDataArray)
    {
        /**
         * Yout Code
         */
        $this->helper->getConfig('my/config/path');
    }

}
```

Remove **var/generation** folder for Magento 2.2 remove **/generated** folder

Comment: Thank you, The Biggest problem for me with all the Trying was Removing the **/generated** folder